# Scope of Stack Allocated Class in a Vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I have classes organized as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Tracker
{
    int a = 0;

    void update()
    {
       a++;
    }
};

struct OtherClass
{
    std::vector<Tracker> activeTrack;

    void updateAll()
    {
       for (Tracker tr : activeTrack) {
           tr.update();
       }
    }
};

int main()
{
    OtherClass o;
    o.activeTrack.resize(1);
    o.updateAll();  // does nothing?!

    std::cout << o.activeTrack[0].a << '\n';  // Is 0; should be 1!
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbeb94101bad8099))

Is there something very simple that I am not understanding about how stack allocated objects behave in vectors?

Comment: Please spend some words in explaining what you actually intend to do. The subsequent edits have also departed from the original code snippet.

Comment: @g24l: Have they? The code is an _equivalent_ version of the OP's code, but in complete, minimal testcase form (which we _require_). There was previously some rambling blurb that was hard to read, which is not necessary as the problem is clearly stated in the code comments. Which part of the edits did you find confusing?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit was pretty clear from the previous version, what part did you find "rambling blurb"? The op has also mentioned about the Tracker having shared ptr inside. Might have been reflected in that version better. Is is not good practice to tailor a question to an answer.

Comment: @g24l: I did not "tailor a question to an answer". I tailored the question to Stack Overflow. The OP only mentioned a shared_ptr as an interesting observation _after the problem was already solved_. There is no need to bring it back up again. Please just ... _stop_ ...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit doesn't seem like it to me, the shared ptr was in Tracker object , which would make ok to copy it and update the value, by pointer. It would be best to have the original code. The test case that you added is pretty evident at any rate.

Comment: @g24l: Well, the author of the question disagrees with you. So let's leave it there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96713/discussion-between-g24l-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit True, no need to get personal. I was just under the impression that your edits have mislead him in believing that an integral type copy and a copy of a shared ptr are one and the same.

Comment: @g24l: I don't see how that could possibly be the case. Once more, I suggest we leave it there. The problem is solved. There is nothing further to be gained from this continued bickering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (Tracker tr : activeTrack) {
   tr.update();
}
```

Here you're making a copy each time, and performing `update()` on the *copy*.

Use a *reference*:

```
for (Tracker& tr : activeTrack) {
   tr.update();
}
```

Comment: That explains it. In the code I was working on I had an OpenCV smart pointer in the Tracker object as well, and that was getting copied and allowing me to update what it pointed to.

Comment: @AdnanEK the shared ptr seems irrelevant . Can you make the posted code more specific .

Comment: @g24l: The posted code is completely specific, Adnan's comment is perfectly clear, and the problem is solved. What are you getting at? Why the downvote? Are you confused?

Comment: The edits that @Lightness Races in Orbit made expressed the problem I was having very well (not properly understanding C++ semantics).

Comment: @AdnanEK I just couldn't figure out why the shared ptr comes into play. Please update your code to specify. Thanks.

Comment: You don't answer this part "Is there something very simple that I am not understanding about how stack allocated objects behave in vectors?" An explanation would be nice.i.e. They are copied , "see my answer"

Comment: It doesn't impact the problem from the question, but knowing that the copy constructor was being called helped me understand why updating an object pointed to by a shared_ptr would still work, but not the update of the int.

Comment: @g24l: That they are copied into the vector is utterly irrelevant. What is important is that the OP was copying them in the iteration, which I did fully address, explain and demonstrate.

Comment: @AdnanEK he is talking about a shared ptr on the tracker object not the activeTrack, which differentiates the problem. Thus the for loop would work if having shared ptr copies of the tracker object in the vector.

Comment: @g24l: I think the OP is better qualified than you are to know what he himself is thinking. Would you please stop trying to confuse people? The problem is solved. This question is over. There is no need for your continued confusion. Thank you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sure , but better reply in context if you may. He says that Tracker had a shared pointer inside that you edited into an integral type. Just after your post.

Comment: @g24l: It's still irrelevant.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit just improving your suggestion to use auto . No need to specify the type.

Comment: @g24l: I know; I actually had that in a grace period revision, but decided there was no gain to be had in changing the code an extra step from the version in the question. All we want to demonstrate is the change from value to reference. Introducing `auto` is something else entirely, and distracts from the point. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit in the original version the OP was also using auto. Maybe better not have edited that either.

Comment: @g24l: No, he wasn't. Either you're looking at some other question (such as the now-duplicate), or deliberately telling falsehoods.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have to give you this, that the OP was not actually using auto.

Answer (score 0):

Vector by default internally always allocates on the heap. To do that it copies what is passed to it. The problem is the range based for loop that you copy the value every time.

Instead, you could use auto to get the iterator

```
for( auto it = activeTrack.begin() ; it != activeTrack.end() ; ++it)
{
  it->update();
}
```

and that way there are no worries about pass-by issues.

Comment: Why would you use iterators here? You're throwing away the whole benefit of range-for, and for no reason.

Comment: _"Vector internally always allocates on the heap"_ This is wrong too. The allocator is configurable.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit true except if the allocator is specified and is indeed such that it allocates on the stack. Too many ifs there . I'll amend a bit to keep you happy.

Comment: Right, so your answer is correct in that sense, as long as "always" means "not always".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "-always" is implementation dependent on "by-default".

Comment: Then write "by default", not "always".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks for the point , taken into account.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks for your edit, but I prefer it as is. Now if you can point me to an actual implementation widely used that the non standard vector allocator does actually allocate the internal storage on the stack, I will rephrase.

Comment: I thought we'd agreed that "always" is incorrect. Never mind, I give up. As for other allocations, um, there are hundreds. Google "C++ allocator" and educate yourself. Pool allocators are, in particular, extremely widely used in all sorts of applications.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit evidently you like to read they way it suits you better. I told you that I took your comments into consideration. "By default" vector "always" assigns on the heap. In c++ it is known that you can override many things to your bidding. One of these deprecated notions is writing a custom allocator, e.g. Operator new. None of the allocators that you cited is actually allocating on explicitly on the stack, and none is widely used.

Answer (score 0):

your iterator was a problem, plus you did not create an instace of tracker to add to the vector, this one works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct Tracker
{
    int a = 0;

    void update()
    {
       a++;
    }
};

struct OtherClass
{
    std::vector<Tracker> activeTrack;

    void updateAll()
    {
       for (vector <Tracker>::iterator it = activeTrack.begin(), end=activeTrack.end(); it != end; ++it)
       it->update();
    }
};

int main()
{
    OtherClass o;
    o.activeTrack.resize(1);
    Tracker T;
    o.activeTrack.push_back(T);
    o.updateAll();  
    std::cout << o.activeTrack[0].a << '\n'; 

 }
```

hope it helps

Comment: Why did you remove the terse C++11 for loop and replace it with an ugly antiquated equivalent?

Comment: Nothin bad with this. It helps reduce compilation times.